# How to display a large image in the center of a smaller div

Tags: html, css, alignment

Is there a way to display a set of images horizontally in the center of a `div` even when the image is wider than the `div`? For instance, if the outer `div` is 100px wide and the image is 200px wide then I want the image center (i.e. at 100px) to be aligned with the center of the containing `div` (i.e. at 50px).

At the moment it works fine when all the images are smaller than the div, but when they are wider, they become left aligned. If they are all the same width, then I can set the scroll position of the div, BUT they are dynamic images and can be any width. Look at the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BRhLy/) for an example.

The intention here is to produce something like a document viewer where each image is a page in the document and would therefore be aligned in the middle.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest the images inside another `div` and set its `display` to `inline-block`

**HTML**

```
<div id="outerdiv">
<div id="innerdiv">
<img src="http://ipsumimage.appspot.com/60x20,ff0000" />
<img src="http://ipsumimage.appspot.com/200x20,ff0000" />
<img src="http://ipsumimage.appspot.com/100x20,ff0000" />
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#outerdiv
{
overflow:auto;
width:100px;
background-color:gray;    
text-align:center;

}
#innerdiv {
display:inline-block;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uSTUG/).

Comment: That was quick! Thanks

Comment: @hofnarwillie You're welcome! You could also check back on this question, if someone posts a better answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well Im just starting out with jquery but I can give you a theoretical answer. Use jquery to take width of parent div. take width of image. find the difference in both and move negatively to the amount in the image.

Example: div width is 50
image width is 100

put position relative on the parent div
put position absolute on image
and put 50-100=50/2(actually 25 as the width is distributed to both sides. 25 to the left and 25 5 to the right.) as the left of the image

```
div parent{
position:relative;
}

div img{
position:absolute;
left:-25; //actually this is the difference of the image and div/2
}
```

Use jquery to do this dynamically

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer jCuber's pure CSS solution to this. Otherwise, if JavaScript is disabled my site would be broken.